# Unable to call method from static WebService method

Tags: apex, webservices, compile-error

I am at a loss as to why I am running into issues here. I am trying to simply make a call to a method within a class, from a web service method.

The error I continue to get is:

> Save error: Non-void method might not return a value or might have statement after a return statement.

I am calling this through `Execute Enonymous`:

```
TestClass.callWebService();

global with sharing class TestClass
{

    void testing()
    {


    }

    WebService static void callWebService()
    {    
        testing(); // doesn't work
        //this.testing() also doesn't work
        //TestClass.test() also doesn't work
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only call `static` methods from within `static` methods. You cannot call instance methods.

**Works**

```
static void doStuff() { /* logic */ }
webservice static void callWebService()
{
    doStuff();
}
```

**Fails**

```
void doStuff() { /* logic */ }
webservice static void callWebService()
{
    doStuff();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was assuming. I found an issue with the code I had (I tried to clean it up for a more simple demonstration), and apparently I deleted the return line at the very end of the web service method.. it wasn't void in my code, so I think the error was telling me that is where the issue was.. but Salesforce and its generic error messages..